# Javascript detect a single defined object out of many objects

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, operators, readability

The verbiage was a little awkward here but I know there's a smart way to go about this. I am requesting data from a JSON object. This JSON object will either have a "city", "town", or "locale". It will only ever have one. I have some verbose layered 'if undefined' checks that just stack on top of each other until I find the right one, but I imagine using operators there must be a better way. This code works, I just believe it can it should be done better. Here's an example:

```
var town = response.data["locale"];
  if(town === undefined){
    town = response.data["town"];
    if(town === undefined){
      town = response.data["city"];
      if(town === undefined){
        town = "N/A";
      }
    }
  }
```

As you can see I just want to assign my variable to whichever one exists. I find this nested "if statement" mess a complete eyesore. Perhaps my problem can help people in the future write cleaner code. I'm not great with operators but this situation doesn't seem to call for use of any ternary operators.

Comment: `let town = response.data.locale || response.data.town || response.data.city || "N/A"` should work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the or (`||`) operator while defining a variable for example. It checks if the first one is undefined, and if it is, it will try to use the second one, etc.

In your case, you can just replace it to this line.

```js
let town = response.data["locale"] || response.data["town"] || response.data["city"] || "N/A";
```

Comment: This is probably the expected answer, but it should be noted that falsy values will be ignored with `||`

Answer (score 3):

You’ve tagged the question with [node.js](/questions/tagged/node.js), so I’ll assume you’re using Node.js and have modern JavaScript available. The [nullish coalescing operator `??`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing_operator) is almost exactly equivalent:

```js
let town = response.data.locale ?? response.data.town ?? response.data.city ?? "N/A";
```

and you can avoid repeating `response` too:

```js
let {data} = response;
let town = data.locale ?? data.town ?? data.city ?? "N/A";
```

(I say “almost exactly equivalent” because it will also fall back on the value `null`, not just `undefined`.)

Comment: You could even destruct response data `const {locale, town, city} = response.data`

Comment: This is exactly the type of operator I was hoping for, but node throws a syntax error on it

Comment: @macmeyers50: It’s only supported in the latest major version of Node; upgrade to Node 14 and you should be good. :)

Comment: @Ry- Really appreciate the help, the two answers I got were exactly what I was looking for. Side question if you see this: how did you know this considering how new support for the operator is?

Comment: @macmeyers50: I keep up with some JavaScript proposals! https://github.com/tc39/proposals